# How to write an integral (not in italic) in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, italic

I wanted to know how to write in LaTeX an integral but not in italic. Please!

Comment: The computer modern font's integral symbol is slanted. If you want an upright symbol for some reason and it's that important to you, I think it would be better to select a font with such a design choice

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify the integral in the standard computer moderns font yourself, or use a font best suited to your interests, for instance see [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) (not all are open fonts).